# Trucaller unable to send media files (images/videos), only contacts

Tags: mms, truecaller

I'm using Truecaller on my Samsung Galaxy Ace J1 SM-J111F and I'm apparently unable to send images or video files, only location and contacts.

[image]

How do I rectify the issue where I am able to send videos and images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trucaller disables this feature when the phone in question lacks sufficient storage space, typically there is only about 100 MB left.